# Regarding integration of a complex valued function

Tags: integration

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be such that $f(z,-t)=f(z,t)$. I am trying to figure if   $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(z,t)dt\stackrel{?}{=}2\int_{0}^{a}f(z,t)dt$$ always holds. What I really need is the integral on the RHS but I can calculate the LHS by use of residue theorem. Are there cases when this can fail?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not require any Complex Anlysis. The integral of  a complex valued function $g+ih$ is $\int g +i\int h$ so the question simply reduces to the equation $\int_{-a}^{a} f(t) dt =2 \int_0^{a} f(t) dt $ for a real valued even function $f$ which is true.